# Url Rewrite Help Removing Question Mark And .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have the following url:

http://example.com/cars.php?category=suv?car_title=benz

I want the url to look like this:

http://example.com/cars/suv/benz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: this question has alot of answers already on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use from this structure in your htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cars/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /car.php?category=$1&car_title=$2 [NC,L]
```